# Why the set of rational numbers is not an order complete field as it is the subset of real numbers which is an order complete field?

Tags: real-analysis

So far as I am concerned an order complete field is that one which have supremum and infimum belonging to that set. And for the proof of the above mentioned question I already have the proofs using some k^2 greater and lesser than 2 which I can't decode.
Please make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Perhaps you should share the proofs you have.

Comment: [This is a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438902/please-make-it-simple?noredirect=1#comment5038274_2438902) - please improve your previous question, rather than asking it again.

Comment: The word "complete" is the key.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I appreciate that

Comment: @NoahSchweber I ain't duplicate, I am the previous one whom you told to find the definition of field.. but somehow they aren't allowing me to ask anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let x be an irrational number , then take two rational sequences **a**n and **b**n (rational sequences means that every term of that sequence is a rational number) such that both of them converge to x and **a**n is less than or equal to **b**n for every natural n.

Then it's easy to show that sup(**a**n)=inf(**b**n)=x but yet x is not a rational number therefore the set of rational numbers is not an order complete field.

Comment: @user479671 You're welcome.I hope my answer helped you with your question!

Comment: Analogously, to show $\Bbb R$ is uncountable: Let $S=\{f(n): n\in \Bbb N\}\subset \Bbb R$ where $f$ is injective and $f(1)<f(2)$....(i).If $S$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ let $g(1)=1$ and $ g(2)=2.$ For $3\leq j\in \Bbb N$ let $g(j+1)$ be the least $n > g(j)$ such that  $f(n)$ is between  $f(g(j))$ and $f(g(j-1)).$  Let $x=\inf \{f(g(2j)): j\in \Bbb N\}.$ If $x=f(n')$ then $g(n)<n'<g(n+1)$ for some $n$, and   $f(n')$ is between $f(g(n))$ and $f(g(n+1)),$ contrary to the def'n of $g(n+1)$. So $x\not \in S$.... (ii). If $S$ is not dense in $\Bbb R$ then $S\ne R.$........+1

Answer (score 0):

Re : "some k^2 greater or less than 2". The idea is to get a  sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ of positive rationals where each $x_n^2>2$ and such that no positive rational is less than every member of $\{x_n^2-2:n\in \Bbb N\}.$

Assume that that $x=\inf_{n\in \Bbb N}x_n$ exists and belongs to $\Bbb Q.$ Note  that $0< x$ (because $1$ is a lower bound for $\{x_n\}_n$ ) and that $x<x_n$ for all $n.$

For any $q\in \Bbb Q^+$ there exists $n$ such that $x^2-2< x_n^2-2<q.$ So $x^2-2$ is less then any positive rational.

Now if $x^2<2$ let $x'=(x+2/x)/2$ and $x''=2/x.$ Then $x<x''\in \Bbb Q$ and $(x'')^2<2$ so $x''<x_n$ for every $n.$ But then $x$ would not be the $greatest$ lower bound for $\{x_n\}_n$. Therefore $x^2\geq 2 .$

So either $x^2-2=0$ (contradicting $x\in \Bbb Q$) or $x^2-2$ is a positive rational that's less than every positive rational  (which is absurd).

Therefore the assumption that some $x\in \Bbb Q$ is equal to $\inf_nx_n$ is paradoxical. So the non-empty subset $\{x_n\}_n$ of $\Bbb Q$ has a lower bound in $\Bbb Q$ but no greatest lower bound in $\Bbb Q,$ so $\Bbb Q$ is not order-complete.

Note : We can obtain $\{x_n\}_n$ by taking any $x_1\in \Bbb Q^+$ such that $x_1^2>2$ and letting $x_{n+1}=(x_n+2/x_n)/2.$ (Reference topic: Heron's method for approximate square roots: Heron (a.k.a. Hero) of Alexandria, circa 100 A.D.)

Answer (score 0):

Another proof is the following. We will use that

1. $\mathbb{Q}^{+}\ni x\mapsto x^2$ is a monotone injection: $y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$
2. If $0<x,y$ are 'close', then $x^2,y^2$ are close too, the idea which motivates the proof

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}^+:2\leq x^2\}$. Since $1^2=1<2$, $1$ is a lower bound of $A$, therefore, if $\mathbb{Q}$ is complete, $c=\inf A$ exists in $\mathbb{Q}$.

We show that
$$1<c<2.\qquad  (*)$$
Since $1$ is a lower bound of $A$, we have to have $1<c$. On the other hand, if $2\leq x$, then $2^2=4\leq x^2$, but then, $2<(5/3)^2<4$, so $5/3\in A$ and $(5/3)<2\leq c$, which contradicts to the definition of $c$.

Now, we examine the value of $c^2$: $c^2$ cannot be equal to two, due to the fact that $x^2-2=0$ cannot be solved in $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, $2<c^2$. We would like to find $\Delta\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ suct that $2<(c-\Delta)^2<c^2$. Such a $\Delta$, if exists leads to a contradiction to the definition of $c$. We have two separate cases

1. Assume $2c<c^2-2$. Note that $0<c-1$ due to $(*)$ and $c-1<c$, so $(c-1)^2<2$. But
   $$(c-1)^2-2=(c^2-2)-2c +1>1,$$
   and so $(c-1)^2>3>2$, a contradiction to $(c-1)^2<2$.
2. Assume $2c\geq c^2-2$. Then, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is Archimedian, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>0$ such that $n^{-1}2c\leq c^2-2$. Of course, $0<c-1\leq c-n^{-1}<c$, therefore $(c-n^{-1})^2<2$. But
   $$(c-n^{-1})^2-2=(c^2-2)-2n^{-1}c+n^{-2}>n^{-2}>0,$$
   resulting in $2<(c-n^{-1})^2$ a contradiction to $(c-n^{-1})^2<2$.